# Instance variable not being recognized by its view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, instance-variables

Can anyone think of a reason why an instance variable declared in the controller would not be recognized by its view?

Controller looks something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

...
def show

@questionshow = session[:profilequestioncapture]
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@question = Question.where("id = ?", @questionshow).first
...
```

And the view: (show.html.erb in the users directory:)

```
...
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
      
    <dt>Headline</dt>
    <dt>Description</dt>
    <dt>Budget</dt> 

    <dd><%= @question.headline %></dd>
    <dd><%= @question.description %></dd>
    <dd><%= @question.currency %>&nbsp<%= @question.budget %></dd>

</dl>
....
```

-the session correctly populates the @questionshow instance variable. It only contains the id, and this gets correctly passed to @question.

-here's what's strange: <%= @user.xxxx %> gets correctly formatted and displayed, whereas anything with <%= @question.xxx %> does not.

-and here's what's even stranger. If I comment out @user in the controller the record is still correctly displayed in the view, so it's effectively ignoring what's in the controller (but I can't figure out why)

-And yes I've checked I'm looking at the right controller & viewer.

Comment: just log your variables and you'll find where you missing something

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that session[:profilequestioncapture] is not nil?

Comment: dead certain. I've logger.debugged it and triple checked.

Answer (score 0):

`@question` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.  unless you call `.first` on it, you'll have errors when you try to call some  of the question attributes to it. and that will also be true if, as stated by one of the answers, `session[:profilequestioncapture]` is nil

Comment: I forgot to add .first to my question above. I've edited the question. But that's not it, it's still now working. The session is populated and I've logged all the other variables. @question.xxx in the view still comes up blank...

Comment: can you check the html source? do you see the `dd` there?

Answer (score 0):

First I think that the where scope will give you an ActiveRecord::Relation (which gives an array), not a record. Since you want to find by id I would suggest

```
Question.find(session[:profilequestioncapture])
```

Most probably you will want to rescue ActiveRecord::NotFound exception and either set a default question or change the behavior.

Are you using Draper or Presenters?
Can you double check your @question actually has data?

As for your @user behind populated even if commented out:

- Check for caching issues
- Check for before_filter actions that could populate it for you.

Comment: I made the change you suggested. There is no reason to convert the session into an integer as it's finding the record I need, it's just need being passed to the view. There is no before_filter and I am not using Draper or Presenters. And @question in the controller has data but not in the view. There is no exception to rescue as I'm no getting an exception, just a blank view. So no luck I'm afraid. Could you elaborate on what you mean by caching issues?

Comment: If you would have an html file of the same name in your public folder or you'd set up your dev env with caching and/or store the value in a cache store. You could be pulling the wrong @user but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but it's left me a bit bewildered. I was not defining the same instance variable attached to my Questions model across all actions in the same controller. So in Show is was @question whereas in Create it was (for example) @yyyquestion and in Update I had used something else (e.g. @yyyquestion). I have no clue why this would cause the error and why the instance variable would be populated in the controller but not in the View. I think there is more to this story...